# How to make values from the database persist locally using python flask and sqlaclchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

The get_varieties() function fetches values from a persistent database. How do I make the fetched values persist locally (or in memory) while the app is running (or in use), such that subsequent calls to this function does not need to make database queries?

Is it wise to use globals?

Should I define get_varieties() in the model?

```
def get_varieties():
    varieties = Variety.query.all()
    return ((i.var_name, i.var_name) for i in varieties)

@bp.route('/aap', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def list_aap():
    items = AAP.query.all()
    form = AAPFilterForm()
    if form.submit():
        filters = [dict(PERIODS_).get(form.period.data),
            dict(get_varieties()).get(form.item.data),      <== called here
            dict(WAREHOUSES_).get(form.warehouse.data)
            ]
    form.period.choices = PERIODS_
    form.item.choices = get_varieties()                     <== also here
    form.warehouse.choices = WAREHOUSES_
    return render_template('pages/listAAP.html', items=items, form=form,
        filters=filters)
```

Comment: flask may run every request in different process (worker) and sometimes global values may not be shared between requests. It is safer to read again from database or use some `cache` system which keeps it in local file.

Comment: @furas, is flask-cache a viable solution for this scenario?

Comment: if `get_varieties()` always gives the same result and it never changed then I would simply assign it to global variable. Every process will have own variable but always with the same values. OR I would create variable with all values directly in model. And of course I would put `get_varieties()` also in model.